# Pause thread until cpu is freed

Tags: c#, .net-core

What I want to achieve is to wait with newly created thread until cpu is under N% load.

The problem is that I cannot measure cpu and memory usage since `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` doesn't work in .NET Core.

Do not know if it is smart to pause a thread in terms of performance.

I have found this code:

```
var proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var mem = proc.WorkingSet64;
var cpu = proc.TotalProcessorTime;
Console.WriteLine("My process used working set {0:n3} K of working set and CPU {1:n} msec", mem / 1024.0, cpu.TotalMilliseconds);

foreach (var aProc in Process.GetProcesses())
    Console.WriteLine("Proc {0,30}  CPU {1,-20:n} msec", aProc.ProcessName, cpu.TotalMilliseconds);
```

but do not understand how that measure cpu/ram usage and how it can help me getting it's usage in `%/MB`

Comment: sounds like an x-y problem. why do you want to pause the thread? the OS will schedule it approrpiately.

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry forgot to mention but edited my question. That thread I want to pause is newly created thread. I want to pause it because it is helping with some work but that work doesn't need to be done so it is only done if cpu/ram is not under load to not hit perfomance

Comment: you could set the thread priority..

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, can not do. Well, you COULD loop and check CPU utilizatoin once per second or so and wait, but seriously, this is wasting threads.

What you CAN do is put up a thread with a low priority.

Comment: Google for "c# prioritize thread"
and
scale on amount of threads. OS will do the schedeuling.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my normal "rate limiting" code:

```
bool continue = true;
int rate = 1;
dateTime dueTime = dateTime.Now.AddMilliSeconds(rate);

while(continue){
  if(dateTime.Now >= dueTime){
    //do your thing.
    dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliSeconds(rate);
  }
  else { 
    Thread.Sleep(1); 
  }
}
```

Note that I had to write it from memory, so my Syntax might be off.

Comment: This seems like a seriously bad idea. There are threading mutexes and semaphores designed to handle this kind of thing properly.

Comment: @Enigmativity: It is a simple implementation of Rate Limiting. Of course there are plenty of ways to improove on it. But it is a good start for beginners none the less.

Comment: No, it's not a good start for beginners. I also wouldn't call it a simple implementation - I would call it dangerous. It is a seriously bad idea. All coders - beginners especially - should avoid it like the plague.

Comment: @Enigmativity: What **exactly** about this has to be "avoided like the plague"*? The OP already said he has a decicated thread. If he had not, I would have mentioned that preceding the code.

Comment: For me the perceived issue was: a)User has a Thread that runs a infinite loop to check if it has work to do b)Thread does not always have work to do. c) a infinite loop would tax out one core with polling. **THAT** is the problem my code is for. My definition of "no work to do" was "not enough time passed" but if you needed help changing a if, I am not sure why you would bother with multitasking.